# Suma de números para graficar

Tags: php, html, highcharts

Realizo una gráfica lo cual necesito que sume el total de horas extras y lo grafique.

El problema es en mi gráfica lo separa y los suma si son iguales es decir; si hay 1+1+1 suma 3 y lo devuelve en una barra lo mismo hace para los siguientes registros y lo que necesito es que todos los sume en una barra sin importar si son iguales y me calcule el total de horas extras.

Saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Estructura tabla calculos**

```
id_Control      Primaria   Índice   int(10)
total_horas                         int(10)
horas_extras                        int(10)
semana                              int(10)
```

Devuelve el nombre de los datos

```
<?php 
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT horas_extras, COUNT(*) total FROM calculos GROUP BY horas_extras");
    while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
?>

    [<?php echo $res['horas_extras']?> ],

<?php
    }             
?>
```

Hace el conteo de los registros

```
<?php 
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT horas_extras, COUNT(*) total FROM calculos 
    GROUP BY horas_extras");
    while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {

?>

      [<?php echo $res['total']?> ],

<?php
    }             
?>
```

Comment: lo que deseas es que evalue todos los registros y luego sumen los que son iguales y esa suma graficarla ?

Comment: @srJJ Buenos dias, si eso es lo que necesito pero no consigo hacerlo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas toda la lógica de cómo debería quedar ese `array` en php y luego pasarlo con un `json_encode()` a javascript. [Este es un ejemplo de Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data) de cómo deberías hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leyendo tu código, y según lo que me dices lo que necesitas es recorrer la consulta antes de imprimirla, comparas valor a valor y si son iguales, los sumas y si no lo agrega, dicho lo anterior el código lo haría así:

```
<?php 
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(horas_extras) AS total FROM calculos ");
    while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
?>

    [<?php echo $res['total|']?> ],

<?php
    }             
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, creo que no es lo que quiero lo único que quiero es que haga una suma de todas las horas extras....

Comment: mas facil aun, entonces quita el if y sumalas, pere edito la respuesta

Comment: entonces eso lo puede hacer desde el sql, en donde le puedes poner  `"SELECT  COUNT(horas_extras) total FROM calculos` y asi te traera el total de la suma de todas las sumas extras....

Comment: realice el cambio que me proporcionaste en la consulta y no muestra ningun registro dentro de la grafica. :(

Comment: perdoname, me equivoque, es... `"SELECT SUM(horas_extras) total FROM calculos`

Comment: Muchas gracias por seguir ayudándome, pero aun la gráfica sale en blanco

Comment: Bro, entonces el probelma ya no es de aqui, sino en donde representas los datos, ya que SUM() te suma todas la filas de ese elemento, teniendo en cuenta que sea numerico

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81710/discussion-between-carlos-and-srjj).